# Dúvida sobre ContainsIgnoreCase em um textBox

Tags: c#, string

O problema está na seguinte descrição :

> Erro  CS1061
>
> "string" não contém uma definição para "ContainsIgnoreCase" e não foi
>   possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "ContainsIgnoreCase" que
>   aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "string" (há uma diretiva de uso
>   ou referência de assembly ausente?)

Criei uma extension la no começo em um public static, mas não adiantou.. 
O que mais eu posso fazer?

Erro acontece no [Passo 2.1]

```
namespace MyMethod 
{
    public static class MyExtensions 
    {
        public static bool ContainsIgnoreCase(this string source, string search)
        {

           return source.IndexOf(search, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0;

        }   
    }    
}
```

Uso

```
private void txtBuscarJogo_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs 
{
    var controles = _todosBotoes.Where(btnArcheAge => (btnArcheAge.Tag as String ??    btnArcheAge.Text).ContainsIgnoreCase(txtBuscarJogo.Text)).ToArray();
    //Passo 2.2
    mainPanel.Controls.Clear();
    //Passo 2.3
    mainPanel.Controls.AddRange(controles);
}
```

Comment: Não use imagens, cole o texto da mensagem de erro.

Comment: Também cuide a formatação do código, quanto mais difícil de ler, menos gente disposta a ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Só falta incluir o *namespace* na classe do `Form`. Aliás, o nome do *namespace* não está bom, tente colocar algo mais descritivo, como `MyExtensionsMethods`.

```
// Outros using
using MyMethod;

namespace SeuNamespace
{
    public partial class Form1 { }
}
```

Comment: caraca, tava sem erro nenhum quando inclui o mymethod, dei start pra testar, e meu programa todo deu erro ! :O, não sei se esbarrei em alguma tecla e apaguei alguma linha, mas meu form nem aparece mais. ERRO :  A classe Form1 pode ser criada, mas não é a primeira classe do arquivo. O Visual Studio requer que os designers usem a primeira classe do arquivo. Mova o código da classe de forma que ela seja a primeira classe do arquivo, e tente carregar o designer novamente.

Comment: Eu queria realmente entender aonde você queria chegar até concordo que o nome poderia ser melhor (poderia) até porque esse `namespace` deveria ter dois nomes separados por `.` sendo muito utilizado assim. acaba isso sendo também opinativo ...

Comment: É, eu acabei escrevendo superficialmente primeiro, mas dps dei uma melhorada.

Comment: @DárioSabaini Não faço ideia do que você fez. Tente um Ctrl + z

Comment: http://prntscr.com/f5lukh parece que eu apaguei algo, ou coloquei algo na ordem errada... mas não faço ideia do que seja

Comment: @DárioSabaini tem muita coisa nesse projeto?

Comment: @DárioSabaini O using precisa estar **antes da declaração da classe**

Comment: Pedi ajuda de um amigo ele disse que normalmente não é bom ter 2 namespace em um projeto. provavelmente foi onde eu to atrapalhado. coloquei o using MyMethod no começo mas mesmo assim não deu certo. vou continuar tentando

Comment: Peça pro seu amigo embasar o que ele disse. Informação sem embasamento é opinião ou achismo e estes dois nada valem =D

Comment: @DárioSabaini fala pro seu amigo que ele ta muito enganado, o que aconteceu com você é outro problema, imagine você pensar assim adicionando uma novo pacote no seu sistema, que tem um `namespace` diferente, informação inválida ...

Comment: Consegui galera !! ERA TÃO SIMPLES... era só colocar aquele namespace la no final do código... pois o form tem que vir primeiro de tudo. Muito obrigado jbueno e compania :)

Comment: @DárioSabaini Tem algo errado. O `using` não precisa estar no final do código. Fora isso, a questão está resolvida? Você precisa de algo mais?